# Use mock service in Seam project

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, seam2, jboss-seam

I'm redesigning an improvement of a platform that already exists developed with Seam framework version 2.1.1.RA2, Java 6 and JBoss 4.2.3.GA and Ivy. I have 4 modules that communicate with each other. I want to modify one of these modules independently of others. I just want to know how to make a simulation of one module using the mock service.

Answer (score 0):

Using beans.xml file you can add alternatives to your project. My suggestion is to use one interface with method definitions and make one bean with real implementation and one with mock implementation. In beans.xml just specify that you want to use class with mock implementation.

http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsBeansxmlAndWhyDoINeedIt.html

Comment: I test your suggestion but it doesn't work I have a project (old one) that use Jboss with seam framework in addition to mock ,I'm having troubles trying to launch this project I want to know how to tell Jboss to use either the mock version of class or the reel class.
ps:in my buil.xml I have this configuration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmR0.png

and in my build.properties I add this lines but not work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9zn4.png

and I have webservices-mock-data folder

In short how to configure Jboss to switch between real class and MOCK version of class